Do I really have a 64-bit or a 32-bit gcc?
I installed MSYS2 on my 64-bit ARM Windows. It of course installs some MINGW stuff, I don't believe I installed any separately.
Now, I go to select a "kit" for the VSCode CMake Tools extension, and the following curious listings pop up:

They are showing a 64 and 32 designation. Now I might easily have ignored this, but whenever I try to debug my build using the CodeLLDB extension, I get this very curious message:
This platform (win32-arm64) is not suported.
I don't know what to make of it. Do those kit designations indicate that it is building 32-bit executables on a 64-bit operating system? (I can see the problem there.) Or do they mean something else? Either CodeLLDB has a bug, or my compiler tools installation has a problem, and I need to understand which.
It is certainly a Windows 64 installation. Here's the system report:


The GCC architecture is x86_64 so it generate 64-bit executables. Unlike Windows with x86_64 processors, who can run most old 32-bit programs, the 64-bit ARM Windows probably can't run 32-bit programs. That's why this message appears.

How did you draw that conclusion about the architecture?  And why am I seeing mingw32 (mingw64) on the kit description? That is just as confusing as it can be!

@Joymaker you can see that from the GCC installed from the list you show, GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32(mingw64). x86_64 means AMD or Intel 64-bit processors, for 32-bit processors it shows i686 or i586 for old Pentiums.

@Joymaker You can however force a 32-bit compile adding a flag -m32 in the command line. GCC is not a Windows native so we use MinGW to use GCC on Windows machines.
